# ADD new column after existing column and DROP existing column with one statement MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I was able to perform adding new columns after one another in a single statement. for eg.

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD `b` VARCHAR(30) AFTER `a`, ADD `c` VARCHAR(30) AFTER `b`
```

given this I understand that query run 1 by 1 requests present in a single statement.

**What I wasn't able to achieve was to add a column `b` after column `a` and Drop the existing column `a` in a single statement query.**

I tried this :

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD `b` VARCHAR(30) AFTER `a`, DROP `a`
```

this returns me error saying: `#1054 - Unknown column 'a' in 'mytable'`

Is there any possibility of performing such actions?

Comment: please create a MCVE here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/ with your DDL and the query

Comment: If you change the statement to ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD `b` VARCHAR(30) , DROP `a`; then a is dropped an b is added - but b is added at the end - not perhaps what you want. I suppose the parser recognises that a will be dropped in your statement and doesn't know where to place b. If you specify another column for b to be placed after the alter statement will do so.

Comment: @P.Salmon that's interesting, because MySQL reference doesn't mention this or I looked too quickly and missed it. It just says that you may add as many ADD/DROP's as you like in one statement, without any limitations mentioned. So if you're right, then it's worth mentioning in the doc. Anyways, I'd appreciate if the question author provides a MCVE

Comment: It seems that the cause is the order of internal execution of the instructions, that is, it seems that first executes `DROP` and then `ADD`, in `ADD` no longer exists `a`.

Comment: @Alexey sorry that I cannot help you with that as I am not aware of db-fiddle functionality and how it works.

Comment: [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t8r6ozTnEPXvpNTV3LEQ4n/0) with two examples.